# Publishing MVC3 app to IIS error - The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, iis-6, publishing-site

I published my website to "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Sem_App" and created a website with physical path "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Sem_App" and port 84. When I browse the website on `http://localhost:84/` I get the following error.

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

I do not want to list contents of the directory anyways, I want to run the default page that used to run in debugging mode of VS 2010. Anybody know what's going on?

I tried running this command and restarted iis but it didn't work
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to enable [**directory browsing option**](http://www.hosting.com/support/iis6/enable-directory-browsing-in-iis-6) in IIS. Check out the below link for ASP.NET MVC deployment to IIS 6. (*For .Net 4.0*)

http://www.codefrenzy.net/2011/10/19/deploying-asp-net-mvc-3-to-iis-6/

Answer (score 4):

go to cmd type this and you're good to go 
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir

windir is typically C:\Windows