# the web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory iis 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, publishing-site

When deploying my ASP MVC 4 application to IIS from my pc It worked , I tried also in my colleague pc and It's working but when I had to do it in my office computer it gives me this error "the web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory" , although there is the same configuration in the three computers : Windows 7 , iis 7 .

- I've checked many question that threats this issue like  [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091103/publishing-mvc3-app-to-iis-error-the-web-server-is-configured-to-not-list-the) and many others but they all recommend to enable directory browsing option in IIS , I've tried this but it's just showing my project content and what I want is to open my site .
- Actually, since I'm using ASP MVC 4 , I don't have to mention a default document because in MVC 4 Its goes to controller and get from there the page to show. Do you have any idea of how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if anyone reached here looking for solution, here is how i resolved it. I deleted all files from my server ( bid directory ) and recopied it and but i recopied all files i missed App_global.asax.dll  and App_global.asax.compiled files. Because these files were missing IIS was giving me this error

```
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
```

As soon as i added these files, it started working perfectly fine.